# New car, sometimes engaging first gear does not catch

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, car, gears, skoda

I cant quite express myself with the proper terminology but I will try,

I have a fresh new car. There is just one issue. Sometimes, very sporadically, usually at crossings I engage first gear to start driving, the lever nicely falls in its place(or at least it feels so) but when releasing the clutch, car makes very bad sound as if the clutch/gear did not connect and the lever starts to vibrate quite a lot. Car obviously cannot go on so I have to quickly engage neutral and again first gear.

I could not find this problem on the internet, the car is new and I am not sure if I should go to a car service or the whole thing is normal and will eventually disappear

Comment: The car is *new to you*? Or is it ***NEW***, never before owned by anyone else? If it is in fact new / never owned, why do you not go back to the new car dealer and let them repair or adjust the shifter at no cost under warranty, or show you what you are doing wrong?

Comment: ...and if it is new (you are the first owner), you should make no attempt to correct the problem yourself.

Comment: Are you also a new driver?

Comment: As MTA is pointing out, please provide the year/make/model of your Skoda.

Comment: @MTA its newly manifactured

Comment: And what is the make and model of your newly manufactured vehicle then?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is causing the problem, but I have a suggestion to help you solve the problem.

First, as Weather Vane says, do not attempt to repair or alter this vehicle or take it for repair to anyone other than a Skoda dealer. The car is new, and any defects should be fixed at no charge under warranty by the dealer. You can void your warranty if you attempt a repair any other way.

**Suggestion:**

Record video with sound to document exactly what is happening. Set up your phone or a GoPro or any other video recording device on the passenger seat or affixed to some other place in the car. The video should clearly see your feet and the gear shift lever. Leave this set up recording for all of your driving until the bad sound happens at least one time. No music! You want to hear the bad sound on video.

If you are doing something wrong to cause the noise, it will be revealed in the video. But if you are doing everything right and the car is malfunctioning, you will have proof. Video doesn't lie!

For example, if you shift into first gear but (without realizing it) you pull back on the shift lever slightly before you release the clutch, you will see this in the video.

Another example, if the shift lever goes all the way to the right position for first gear and you take your hand off the shift lever, but the lever pops out of gear when you release the clutch, you will see this too.

Also, once you have video proof that your new car is malfunctioning, it gives Skoda a very strong incentive to fix your car. They certainly don't want to see a video like that posted on social media.